# Getting error while running my ionic project on devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i am getting the following error on my device when running it,where as it runs withour erron on browser and only one of my device and check all the devices but same problem

can any one help me

Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object ionic.bundle.js:9110
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS https://cdn.auth0.com/client/cWQeRf3L4Ength5tIFSrPhrNPUHgO6yQ.js?t1439965186084
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D ionic.bundle.js:22980

```js
// Ionic Starter App


// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers','starter.directives',  'auth0',
  'angular-storage',
  'angular-jwt', 'ngFileUpload','ngResource','ngRoute'])


.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
])

.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|cdvfile|content):|data:image\//);
})




.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
 

 
/*File factory for browse*/
.factory("$fileFactory", function($q) {



    var File = function() { };
console.log("This is in file factory");
    File.prototype = {

        getParentDirectory: function(path) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path, function(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.getParent(function(result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }, function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getEntriesAtRoot: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
   console.log("This is in get Entries in root");
            window.webkitrequestFileSystem(1, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
                directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    deferred.resolve(entries);
                }, function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getEntries: function(path) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path, function(fileSystem) {
                var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
                directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    deferred.resolve(entries);
                }, function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };

    return File;

})


.factory('Post', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://104.155.192.54:8080/api/logins');
})

.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
})
/*This is file browser in ionic */




.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])


.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['*'];
    }
 ])
.factory('merchantRegisterFactory', function($http) {
  var urlBase = 'http://104.155.192.54:8080/api/merchantlogins';
  var _loginService = {};
 
  _loginService.getLogins = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase);
  };
 
  _loginService.saveLogin = function(login) {
   console.log("This is factory is merchantlogins app.js save");
    return $http.post(urlBase,login);
  };
 
  _loginService.updateLogin = function(login) {
    return $http.put(urlBase, login);
  };
 
  _loginService.deleteLogin = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
  };
 
  return _loginService;
})

.factory('addOffer', function($http) {
  var urlBase = 'http://104.155.192.54:8080/api/addoffers';
  var _addofferService = {};
 
  _addofferService.getOffers = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase);
  };
 
  _addofferService.saveOffer = function(login) {
   console.log("This is factory is addoffers app.js save");
    return $http.post(urlBase,login);
  };
 
  _addofferService.updateoffer = function(login) {
    return $http.put(urlBase, login);
  };
 
  _addofferService.deleteOffer = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
  };
 
  return _addofferService;
})




.factory('loginsFactory', function($http) {
  var urlBase = 'http://104.155.192.54:8080/api/logins';
  var _loginService = {};
 
  _loginService.getLogins = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase);
  };
 
  _loginService.saveLogin = function(login) {
   
   
   
   console.log("This is factory Login is app.js save");
    return $http.post(urlBase,login);
  };
 
  _loginService.updateLogin = function(login) {
    return $http.put(urlBase, login);
  };
 
  _loginService.deleteLogin = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
  };
 
  return _loginService;
})




.run(function($rootScope, auth, store, jwtHelper, $location) {
  // This events gets triggered on refresh or URL change
  var refreshingToken = null;
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
    var token = store.get('token');
    var refreshToken = store.get('refreshToken');
    if (token) {
      if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
          auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
        }
      } else {
        if (refreshToken) {
          if (refreshingToken === null) {
              refreshingToken =  auth.refreshIdToken(refreshToken).then(function(idToken) {
                store.set('token', idToken);
                auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), idToken);
              }).finally(function() {
                  refreshingToken = null;
              });
          }
          return refreshingToken;
        } else {
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      }
    }

  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider,
  jwtInterceptorProvider) {
  
  
   jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function(store, jwtHelper, auth) {
    var idToken = store.get('token');
    var refreshToken = store.get('refreshToken');
    // If no token return null
    if (!idToken || !refreshToken) {
      return null;
    }
    // If token is expired, get a new one
    if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(idToken)) {
      return auth.refreshIdToken(refreshToken).then(function(idToken) {
        store.set('token', idToken);
        return idToken;
      });
    } else {
      return idToken;
    }
  }

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
  
  
  
  $stateProvider

  
  
  

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.addoffer', {
    url: "/addoffer",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
         templateUrl: "templates/addoffer.html",
    controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.browse', {
    url: "/browse",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
      }
    }
  })
    .state('app.playlists', {
   cache: false,
      url: "/playlists",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
          controller: 'ExampleController'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
   cache: false,
    url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
        controller: 'ExampleController'
      }
    } 
  });
  
   authProvider.init({
    domain: 'lokaloffers.auth0.com',
    clientID: 'cWQeRf3L4Ength5tIFSrPhrNPUHgO6yQ',
    loginState: 'login'
  });

  
  
  
  
  
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
})
.run(function(auth) {
  // This hooks all auth events to check everything as soon as the app starts
  auth.hookEvents();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; script-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">
    <title></title>
    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above    -->
    <!-- <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
 <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
 
 <!-- ngCordova script -->
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script> 
 <!-- Auth0 Lock -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/auth0-lock/build/auth0-lock.js"></script>
 <!-- auth0-angular -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/auth0-angular/build/auth0-angular.js"></script>
 <!-- angular storage -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/a0-angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.js"></script>
 <!-- angular-jwt -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
 <!--
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqGXcExPSUxrVMpnfBciUejJRU06ZYelE&amp;sensor=true"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places&amp;signed_in=true"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_cy8C8pj5urqUSWERE-qU8NmkoNg6jpk&amp;sensor=true"></script>
 -->
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/countries.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    // 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]    = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET]    = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]       = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]    = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]    = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]    = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]       = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }

    </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's quite hard to see where could be the problem if we don't get the faulty part of your code... The most I can see is the "Failed to load resource" error... If it does load in your browser but not in your phone, it may be because you need to do `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` and add `<access origin="*" />` in your config file.

Comment: hi  thanks for the reply  the cordova-plugin-whitelist is already added and <access origin="*" /> is also added in config file

Comment: so android has a fragmented and outdated webview. that could be the problem, i would highly recommend doing a build with the crosswalk engine https://crosswalk-project.org/, also just checking but you are actually building and installing on the device correct?

Comment: yes i am installing on my device ,the thing is that its running without any errors on my samsung s4 ,where as installed on any other mobile this error is coming

Comment: HI Thanks for the suggession but i solved my problem its the error with ionic CLI updated to latest and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

HI Thanks for the suggession but i solved my problem its the error with ionic CLI ,updated it to latest and it works fine